# Does expo over the air updates work with bare workflow?

Tags: react-native, expo, code-push

I am working on an app which has been expo ejected, so switched to bare workflow. Previously it had Expo over the air updates working. But now Expo.Updates is undefined.

1. Can't we do over the air updates when running app with bare
   workflow?
2. Can we use appcenter codepush in expo bare workflow?

Comment: Not sure about #2, but #1 is addressed at length in the official docs -- https://docs.expo.dev/bare/updating-your-app/

Comment: Thanks @Atmas..